# Neumann's Random Generator - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on Code Abbey problem 23, Neumann's Random Generator.  The goal is to use a given algorithm to generate a series of random numbers from each value in the list, and continue until the algorithm produces the same number we began with.  Then, print the number of passes needed to reach the loop.  I can't seem to get my code to work; I'm quite sure that it's something to do with the while loop.  I would appreciate any help, and more so, an explanation as to what I was doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
cases = int(input())
values = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

def random_number(values):
    for value in values:
        random = pow(value, 2)
        passes = 0
        equal = False

        while not equal:

            if len(str(random)) < 8:
                random = int(str(random).zfill(8))

            random = (random // 100) % 10000

            passes += 1

            if random == value:
                equal = True
            else:
                random = pow(random, 2)

        print(passes, end=' ')

random_number(values)
```

and here's my input:

```
12
6239 8935 4715 8785 9737 9251 3251 3544 9631 4655 903 7589
```

Comment: you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry - The problem is that somehow, I've created an infinite loop.  But I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**
The middle-square method doesn't always return to the starting seed, however this is the only outcome that you test for. The sequence can return to some already-visited number other than the seed, in which case `random` will never equal `value`, and your program won't detect the repetition. (For a quick demonstration of this, try executing the algorithm by hand with the starting a value 12 - you'll find it starts repeating very quickly, but never again visits 12).

**The solution:** Instead of just storing the original value and comparing `random` with that, you need store a list of every value visited so far, and terminate when `random` appears anywhere in that list.

Comment: Most welcome! Now that you've solved it, I recommend checking out the Wikipedia page on the [middle-square method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method). It has a neat Python implementation that you might want to take the time to understand. I don't know whether Code Abbey does this, but I really like the way that Project Euler gives you access to a forum _after_ you've successfully answered a question - I use it as an opportunity to get an insight into more efficient/elegant solutions to the problem I've just solved.